# wait for the function to finish before proceeding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to piece together a nodejs/DynamoDB app (first time doing anything in js). When saving a new record I have to scan the table first and then based on the result of the scan save a new record. After reading a bit I tried something like this

```
router.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('scan here');
  var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    ProjectionExpression: "id",
    FilterExpression: 'id between :start_id and :end_id',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":start_id": c.find(cty => cty.ccode === req.body.country_code).ids,
      ":end_id": c.find(cty => cty.ccode === req.body.country_code).ids + 998
    },
  };
  docClient.scan(params, onScan);

  function onScan(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
      data.Items.forEach(function (n) {
        idarr.push(n.id);
      });
    }
    let maxid = Math.max(...idarr);
    newid = ++maxid;
  }
  console.log('scan done, newid :' + newid);
  next();
}, (req, res) => {
  console.log('and save here');
  // save goes here
  res.send('all done');
});
```

But in the console I'm getting

```
scan here
and save here
scan done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your **scan goes here** code as well. You might be doing some async operation there.

Comment: Added the scan part

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Bogdan, you have to use async await pattern. Assume your `scanRecord` is async, then:

```
router.get("/test", async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('scan here');
  await scanRecord()
  console.log('scan done');
  next();
}, async (req, res) => {
  console.log('and save here');
  await saveToDatabase()
  res.send('all done');
});
```

Try to find information about Promises and async await functions.

Answer (score 0):

Because the task is async, you need to declare async arrow function and await for scan.